# Angularjs / Ionic always show 2 decimal places

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a an input form with the following html

Which prints price as 
{{item.myvalue}}

if I enter the price as 2.15 it prints as 2.15.  However, if I enter it as 2.00 it prints as 2.  I would like to print it as 2.00.  How do I go about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `number` filter:

```
{{item.myvalue | number:2}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a custom filter:

```
angular.module('app')
.filter('fixTwoDecimal', function() {
    return function(num) {
        if(!num) return;
        var result = String(num);
        if(result.indexOf('.') === -1) result = result + '.00';
        else {
            var parts = result.split('.');
            if(parts[1].length === 1) result = result + '0';
        }
        return result;
    }
});
```